# Does anyone have any experience with 500-server errors?

Tags: cloud

Since about 1 hour (11:20 28-09-2021)I have a 500 Internal Server error and have no clue how to solve it. I reset the Google Cloud VM-Instance and have upgraded the instance to more internal memory.

Any clues? Could the machine be hacked?

Appreciate all the help,
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any logs to trace the error? It may be a problem with the code, but without logs its really difficult to know what happened

Comment: Please provide more detail about what application is running on your server and what is in the output logs.  Not only will this help diagnose the problem, but will also help anyone searching for answers with the same problem.